# Question content is altered when editing tags from a question that have special chars

Tags: bug, tags, edits

When I try to edit tags of a question that have special characters in the body of the question the original content is altered without I touch in it.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097075/know-which-algorithm-is-used-program-written-in-vb6). I'm tring to remove the tag "Cypher" (because the Cypher referred in this question is not the Query Language). This question has a code block with some special chars.

```
"rFnJa‡‰¢ iv«¯ŸcŠ›••Š«†›‚‹v¥nZr"
```

After I click in the edit button some of these chars are changed to "little retangles" chars, as you can see in the images below.

As consequence after I remove the Cypher tag and click in the Save button I'm receiving the error message:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to
>   improve in this post?

If more that 5 chars would have been exchanged I would have saved an edit decharacterizing the original question because I would not have noticed the question body change.

The original post:

[image: Original post]

After I click in the edit button:

[image: After click edit]

- SO: Arch Linux
- Browser: Google Chrome 59.0.3071.86 64 bits

Comment: Is there something with my eyes or are the freehand red circles at the wrong spot because I honestly don't see a difference.

Comment: @rene edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: @rene Took me a minute, too. In the second screenshot there are squares not present in the first, near the end of the code block.

Comment: These characters are actually present in the string, you just can't see them in the original post.  Respectively U+009D, U+009D and U+0081.  These codepoints are control characters and don't have a glyph, thus the rectangle.  Why Chrome shows them in the edit view is hard to guess, it just does I guess.  Otherwise standard GIGO, garbage-in, garbage-out :)